# run php script from database record without using eval()

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, eval

I would like to know how to run the php scripts which are stored in the database without using eval().

**The expected process is as follow**

> When user POST a string which contains `{{`*typed_alias* `}}`, the system will search the table whether this alias has record in the `alias` column.
>
> **If yes** -> replace what user typed with the correspond script which is stored in the `replacement` column.
>
> **If not** -> show the original string including `{{` *wrong_alias* `}}`

**The expected result is as follow**

> **When user posts**
>   *Hello, {{morninggg}}, the current unix time is {{nowTime}}*
>
> **Array output from db**
>
> array
>
> ```
>  0 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 445
>      'alias' => 'morning'
>      'replacement' => 'Good morning'
>  1 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 446
>      'alias' => 'nowTime'
>      'replacement' => time()
>  2 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 447
>      'alias' => 'tommorowNow'
>      'replacement' => time()+86400
> ```
>
> **Return**
>
> *Hello, {{morninggg}}, the current unix time is 147855220*

Now I have already solved the database array by using `foreach` and also can replace the alias with script by using `str_replace()`.

**Current classI use to foreach data from database and do the replacement is as follow**

```
class replace {
    public $definitions;

    public function setDefinitions($definitions) {
        $this->definitions = $definitions;
    }

    public function tag($input) {
        if($this->definitions && is_array($this->definitions)) {
            foreach ($this->definitions as $definition) {
                if($defintion['alias'] == 'time') {
                    $input = str_replace('{{' . $definition['alias'] . '}}', date('Y-m-d'), $input);
                } else {
                    $input = str_replace('{{' . $definition['alias'] . '}}', $definition['replacement'], $input);
                }
            }
        }
        return $input;
    }
}
```

**Current using method**

```
$replace = new replace();
$replace->setDefinitions($tagEngine);
$parsedString = $replace->tag($__input);

//$__input is what user POST to the server

echo $parsedString;
```

**However, the current result is as follow**

> *Hello, {{morninggg}}, the current unix time is time()*

The script can't be run successfully on the page

**But when I give the definition manually like this**

> `$definition = array('morning' => 'Good Morning', 'nowTime' => time());
>        foreach ($definition as $key => $value)
>        $source = str_replace('{{' . $key . '}}', $value, $source); 
>        return $source;`

**The script can be run and returns**

> *Hello, {{morninggg}}, the current unix time is 147855220*

I know that using `eval()` can run the scripts, however, it is regarded as a dangerous method in a real-world application by people.

Can anyone give me suggestions about how to deal with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than using `eval()`, except not storing PHP code in your database. Which is exactly what you should do.

Comment: @Acule , thanks for your advice. But why can I run `time()` when I give the definition manually.

Comment: @Mark Because the database returns a string and eval() executes the string as code.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. If there is any security holes (such as a SQL injection hole), you've just opened up the ability for someone to execute their own code on your server, which could do anything from spamming, to distributing viruses and worse.

I strongly recommend you add some logic to this, such as a special flag, then use if statements in your code to spot it's "special" and inject the relevant hard-coded value. And make sure you santitise your database inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use functions like `eval()` to fix this. You should pull all php-code out of your database and parse the different aliasses as follows (I have just altered the `tag()` method in the `replace` class:

```
public function tag($input) {
    if($this->definitions && is_array($this->definitions)) {
        foreach ($this->definitions as $definition) {
            $replacement = $definition['replacement'];
            switch($definition['alias']) {
                case 'nowTime':
                    $replacement = date('Y-m-d');
                    break;
                case 'tommorowNow':
                    $replacement = date('Y-m-d', (time() + 86400));
                    break;
            }
            $input = str_replace('{{' . $definition['alias'] . '}}', $replacement, $input);
        }
    }
    return $input;
}
```

As you can see, for every php-code alias, you can add another `case` in the `switch()` statement. You can read up on the `switch()` control structures at the following link:

> [PHP: switch - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)